# Store values from multiple arrays into one array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, object, foreach

I am trying to put values from several arrays into one string and then those strings put into a new array.

In the code bellow, I loop through a XML file. If I dump the $p element inside the loop just right under, it gives me back this group of arrays:

```
array (4)
    id => "1" (5)
    number => "number example" (10)
    name => " name example " (37)
array (4)
    id => "2" (4)
    number => "number example 1" (10)
    name => " name example 1" (56)
array (4)
    id => "3" (5)
    number => "number example 2" (12)
    name => "name example 2" (40)
array (4)
    id => "4" (5)
    number => "number example 3" (14)
    name => "name example 3" (34)
```

Now, here is the loop code, which I talk about right above.

```
$array=[];
foreach ($array['a']['b']['c'] as $p) {
    $array[] = [
    $p["id"]=>$p["name"] . $p["number"]
    ]
}
```

The problem of my code is, that it returns me this group of another arrays:

```
array (4)
    0 => array (1)
        1=> "number namename example 1" (21)
    1 => array (1)
        2 => "number namename example 2" (21)
    2 => array (1)
        3 => "number namename example 3" (21)
    3 => array (1)
        4 => "number namename example 4" (21)
```

But the goal I try to achieve, is this kind of array:

```
array (4)
     1 => "number namename example 1" (21)
     2 => "number namename example 2" (21)
     3 => "number namename example 3" (21)
     4 => "number namename example 4" (21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the loop to the following:

```
foreach ($array['a']['b']['c'] as $p) {
    $array[$p['id']] = $p["name"] . $p["number"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this php array_merge function:

```
$arr1 = array(1,2);
$arr2 = array(3,4);
$res = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Ok this should work, but the code above is only example. In reality, I have 7 000 results and I cant write 7 000 merges like this...

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=[];
foreach ($array['a']['b']['c'] as $p) {
    $array[$p[$id]] = [$p["name"] . $p["number"]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, I jsut accepted answer above which was faster.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is:

```
foreach ($array['a']['b']['c'] as $p) {
    $array[$p['id']] = $p["name"] . $p["number"];
}
```

Here you add a **string** as element of array under a certain key `$p['id']`.

Comment: This works as well, I just accepted the answer above, as you both had answered in same time